# Convert a Kotlin Class to Hashmap

Tags: android, kotlin

I have a class namely Club which registers new clubs via my app. The class is as under:

```
    class Club {
        var docId = ""
        var clubName = ""
        var yearOfEstablishment = ""
        var postalAddress = ""
        var district = ""
        var subDivision = ""

    }
```

I want to sort registered clubs by `yearOfEstablishment`, by `district` or by `subDivision`, or a combination of all three.

In the below-mentioned code `searchItemsHash` is a HashMap that holds the key and value that I want to check in each Club.

```
for (club in Model.clubList){
      for (searchItem in searchItemsHash){
           //searchItem.key is one of the members of the Club Object
           //searchItem.value is the value of the member of the Club Object.
      }
}
```

My problem is how to iterate through all properties/members of the Club object and compare desired properties with the hashmap.

Comment: You could do it via reflection, but I wouldn't suggest it.  Reflection is generally slow, and mostly considered an antipattern (there are legit uses of it, but they're rare).  The fact you need this seems to say that something in your data modeling is not correct in your app.  Either this should always be a map, or you ought to be writing more specific code that uses these as kotlin objects.  Going half and half kind of smells.

Comment: Also depending on how many of these you have, using a database may be a better option.  Searching a set of objects based on fields screams db.